# Different uses of the value parameter in sem_init(...) in c

Tags: c, semaphore

Suppose I initialize a semaphore in two different ways

1. `sem_init(&randomsem,0,1)`
2. `sem_init(&randomsem,0,0)`

Now,

Will `sem_wait(&randomsem)` work in both the cases

**or**

Will it work only for `sem_init(&randomsem,0,1)`, as using `sem_wait(&randomsem)`  decrements the **value parameter**  when it is **greater than 0** and hence will not work if my semaphore is initialized as `sem_init(&randomsem,0,0)` ??

Which statement is right?? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);
```

sem_init initializes the semaphore object pointed to by sem. The count associated with the semaphore is set initially to value. The pshared argument indicates whether the semaphore is local to the current process ( pshared is zero) or is to be shared between several processes ( pshared is not zero).

The third parameter, value, sets the initial value of the semaphore. So in the the first case your semaphore starts with a value of 1, in the second cast 0;